# Can not Redirect from https://www to https://non www in Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

Now

- http://example.com -> redirect to https non www
- http://www.example.com-> redirect to https non www
- https://example.com-> redirect to https non www
- https://www.example.com can not redirect to  https non www

I tried many way to https://www to https non www
but can not

Here is htaccess file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect to non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # This made the trick for me
    # Remove index.php from the url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you can include dots without escaping in regex? Try changing ^www.example.com to ^www\.example\.com

Comment: I tried but can not

Comment: Where is it redirecting to at the moment? Or is it even redirecting?